# What is the mid-term election in India?

Tags: election, parliament, india, summary-request

I just wanted someone to explain me in a simple manner what the mid-term election in India is.

What are the requirements and how is it conducted ?

Answer (score 2):

Elections to the [Lok Sabha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lok_Sabha) (the lower house of India's parliament) take place every 5 years. The last elections were in 2019, so the next scheduled elections will happen in 2024.

Any elections that occur before that time can be called "midterm" elections. There are two ways that an election could occur before 2024.

First the State Legislative Assembly in each State will hold its own elections. Some states have aligned their regional elections with the National election, but not all. Delhi will hold elections in 2020 and Gujarat is expected to hold elections in 2022, for example. Such elections are conducted according to the constitution of the individual state.

Secondly, it is possible that the government will have to call early elections. This last happened in 1999 after the BJP lost a confidence motion by a single vote. Such early elections are also sometimes called "midterm" elections. Such elections are run in the same way as other elections to the Lok Sabha.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. Could you tell me why is Karnataka gearing up for mid-term elections because the state elections were concluded last year.

Comment: That's a new question. I can find no evidence that Karnataka is preparing for mid-terms, but I speculate that the minority BJP regional government could be close to collapse, leading to fresh regional elections.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.indiatoday.in/amp/india/story/never-wanted-son-hd-kumaraswamy-to-be-cm-of-jds-congress-coalition-govt-says-deve-gowda-1553224-2019-06-21

Comment: Great, go ask a new question.